# Why is NHibernate AdoTransaction's finalizer called?

Tags: nhibernate, dispose, finalizer

I'm profiling out unit & integration tests, and I find the a lot of the time is spent on the finalizer of NHibernate.Transaction.AdoTransaction - this means it is not getting disposed properly.

I am not using AdoTransaction directly in the code, so it's probably used by some other object inside NHibernate. Any idea what I'm forgetting to Dispose?

Here is my text fixture:

```
public abstract class AbstractInMemoryFixture
{
    protected ISessionFactory sessionFactory;
    protected ILogger Logger { get; private set; }
    static readonly Configuration config;
    private static readonly ISessionFactory internalSessionFactory;

    static AbstractInMemoryFixture()
    {
        config = new NHibernateConfigurator().Configure(NHibernateConfigurators.SQLiteInMemory());
        internalSessionFactory = config.BuildSessionFactory();
    }

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        const string sqliteInMemoryConnectionString = "Data Source=:memory:;Version=3;Pooling=False;Max Pool Size=1;";
        var con = new SQLiteConnection(sqliteInMemoryConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        new SchemaExport(config).Execute(false, true, false, true, con, System.Console.Out);
        var proxyGenerator = new ProxyGenerator();

        sessionFactory = proxyGenerator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithTarget(internalSessionFactory, new UseExistingConnectionInterceptor(con));
        Logger = new NullLogger();

        ExtraSetup();
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        var con = sessionFactory.OpenSession().Connection;
        if (con != null)
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }
    }

    private class UseExistingConnectionInterceptor :IInterceptor
    {
        private readonly SQLiteConnection connection;

        public UseExistingConnectionInterceptor(SQLiteConnection connection)
        {
            this.connection = connection;
        }

        public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
        {
            if (invocation.Method.Name != "OpenSession" || invocation.Method.GetParameters().Length > 0)
            {
                invocation.Proceed();
                return;
            }
            var factory = (ISessionFactory) invocation.InvocationTarget;
            invocation.ReturnValue = factory.OpenSession(connection);
        }
    }
    protected virtual void ExtraSetup() { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem while accessing a Sybase database. I don't know why, nor if it's really the reason of the issue, but it appears that some of the code in [`\NHibernate\Transaction\AdoTransaction.cs`](http://nhibernate.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/nhibernate/trunk/nhibernate/src/NHibernate/Transaction/AdoTransaction.cs?revision=4266&view=markup) (lines 307 to 311) related to closing/disposing the object have been disabled for a while. Unfortunately, the blame feature of SVN does not give too much info :(